# NullPointerException when instantiating object with mocks

Tags: java, junit, testng

I am mocking an object and on instantiation I am getting null pointer exception.

Example:

```
public class MyTestClass {
    @MOCK
    private constructorarg1;
    @MOCK
    private constructorarg2;
    @MOCK
    private constructorarg3;
    private myObj;

    @BeforeMethod 
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        myObj = new myObj(constructorarg1, constructorarg2, constructorarg3); //nullpointerexception
    }
}

public class myObj extends myObj1 {
    public myObj(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
         super(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    }      
}

public class myObj1 extends myObj2 {
     private arg_;
     public myObj(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
         super(arg1, arg2)
         arg_ = arg1
     }
}

public class myObj2 {
     private someobj1;
     private someobj2;
     private someobj3;
     public myObj(arg1, arg2) {
         someobj2 = someobj1.add(this, arg2);
         someobj3 = someobj2.getIterator(arg2) //null pointer exception
     }
}
```

myObj is a subclass of an object that is a subclass of another object which is where the null pointer exception is coming from. Do mocks stop occurring if there is an object several levels deep?

Comment: Show the code for the constructor. If you are using the mocked objects, you need the define the expected behavior. Also, don't the arguments need to have a type defined?

Comment: @clinomaniac added constructor. I didn't define the object types for simplicity.

Comment: Need to see myObj1 constructor as well since you are calling it. What I am looking for is if you are calling some methods on the arguments or using them in a way that would throw the null pointer exception. Mocked objects will be null in most use cases unless the behavior is defined.

Comment: @clinomaniac I think you're right. MyObj2 is calling a method with no behavior defined for it and I don't have access to that object.

Comment: Right. So to fix that, you can set expected behavior for the mocked object so that it works as expected.